# Database: deleting child records when the foreign key is on the parent

Tags: database, oracle

I have a pair of tables in an Oracle database with a one-to-one parent-child relationship. Unfortunately the foreign key is defined in the parent, not the child:

```
-----------------        -----------------        
| messages      |        | payloads      |
-----------------        -----------------
| id            |        | id            |
| payload_id    |------->| content       |
| creation_date |        -----------------
-----------------
```

The relationship from `messages.payload_id` to `payloads.id` is enforced by a non-deferrable foreign key.

We have a query that deletes all messages and payloads where message creation date is after a certain time. Unfortunately, due to the backwards foreign key, the current query looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM messages WHERE creation_date < deletion_date;
DELETE FROM payloads WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT payload_id FROM messages);
```

The second nasty delete statement is the problem, as it takes more than an hour when we have ~50 million records in each table.

*Is there a better way to delete all messages and payloads?*

Note that unfortunately the schema is beyond our control...

Comment: What is exactly is backwards? The diagram looks like "messages" has a "payload_id references payloads.id" which seems fine...

Comment: I guess "backwards" is the wrong word - the payload belongs to the message, and with creation_date on the message this means that payloads can't be deleted before messages, making the whole thing awkward...

Comment: Seems like a good case for ON DELETE CASCADE. But as you say, you cannot change the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could log the id's that you're going to delete into a global temporary table and then issue the deletes, optimising the delete from "messages" by storing the rowid as well

```
insert into my_temp_table (messages_rowid, payload_id)
select rowid, payload_id
from   messages
where  creation_date < deletion_date;

delete from messages
where  rowid in (select messages_rowid from my_temp_table);

delete from payload
where  id in (select payload_id from my_temnp_table);

commit;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
DELETE FROM payloads WHERE id IN 
  ( SELECT payload_id FROM messages WHERE creation_date < deletion_date)
```

This needs to run before deleting from messages, of course.

Comment: Tried this: unfortunately this breaks the foreign key from payload_id in messages...